# Why is pandas.DataFrame.explode() not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains two columns (*a* and *b*) and my dataframe looks like this:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100,200 | 100,200,300 |
| 1 | 300,400,500 |  |

I want to use explode() to convert my data to something like:

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 100 | 100 |
| 1 | 200 | 200 |
| 2 | NaN | 300 |
| 3 | 300 | NaN |
| 4 | 400 | NaN |
| 5 | 500 | NaN |

And here's a snippet of my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['100,200','300,400,500'],'b':['100,200,300','']})
df['a'] = df['a'].str.split(',')

df['b'] = df['b'].str.split(',')
df
```

The output of the code is as follows:

```
                 a                b
0       [100, 200]  [100, 200, 300]  
1  [300, 400, 500]               []
```

And then I used explode() but it gives me the following error:

```
df.explode(['a','b']) 
# ValueError: columns must have matching element counts
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the Pandas developers expect that the cells in each row have the same number of elements. That assumption simplifies the index alignment greatly.

You case is can be split into steps:

- explode each column separately
- align the exploded columns by enumeration within each index (row). This can be done via `groupby().cumcount()`
- finally outer join.

So something like this:

```
def my_explode(s: pd.Series) -> pd.DataFrame:
    d = s.explode().to_frame()
    return d.set_index(d.groupby(d.index).cumcount(), append=True)

my_explode(df['a']).join(my_explode(df['b']), how='outer')
```

Output:

```
       a    b
0 0  100  100
  1  200  200
  2  NaN  300
1 0  300     
  1  400  NaN
  2  500  NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Why is there an empty cell in the fourth row? How can I resolve that?

Comment: Because your example has an empty string. and `''.split(,) == ['']`. You can replace the empty string with `NaN` before explode in the function, like this: `d=s.replace('', np.nan).explode().to_frame()` or just drop it, like this: `d = s.loc[s.neq('')].explode().to_frame()`.